# GroupBy with Id of possible null object

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<Item>`

Each Item have a Program, which have an Id.

If an Item is not yet linked to a program, It's program will be null.

I'd like to group all Items by it's Program's Id

That's what I've tried:

```
var listaAgrupada = client.ListarItens(null, null, null).GroupBy(x => x.Programa.Id).ToList();
```

This works if all Items have a program. But if a program is null, it throws an System.NullReferenceException:

> Message = "Object reference not set to
>   an instance of an object."

I believe this is due to the fact that, as Program is null, I can't access it's Id.

I need all Items, even if their program is null (and I'd like them grouped by null program either), so excluding them is not an option.

I've thought in two possible solutions, but I'm not sure how to do any of them:

One would be something like this `GroupBy(x => x.Programa == null || x.Programa.Id)` (which doesn't work)

The other would be add an empty program object where program is null, but I don't know how to do this

Of course, I'm also open to other solutions

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you make a list item, Assign it a 'null' value that you will never use like EMPTY for a string or -99999 for a int

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Assuming you can group all the `null` Programs together and `Id` will be non-negative, how about something like this:

```
GroupBy(x => x.Programa == null ? -1 : x.Programa.Id)
```

Answer (score 26):

With the new C# 6.0 you can also use:

```
.GroupBy(x => x.Programa?.Id)
```

where the `?.` is the null-conditional operator. This possibility was not available when the question was asked.

Comment: I think you should put it like GroupBy(x => x?.Programa?.Id) this then due to the fact that in his case the Programma property is null not the Item :)

Comment: @Martijn Thanks for that correction. I corrected my answer. I decided to not handle the case where `x` (the `Item` itself) is null (that will still blow up), but only the case where `Programa` is null. This is how I interpret the question, and similar to the spirit of the answer by dcp.

Comment: I spent the last week trying to resolve this issue. I had a problem in a left join, and I thought that the problem was when I tried to set a possible null value on `select new`... And the whole time the issue was the `groupby`. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Mixing both answers, this also can be use:

```
.GroupBy(x => x?.Programa?.Id ?? -1)
```

Using "??" defines a default value in case "x" or "x.Program" are null.